# How to make login form for 3rd party login service

Tags: php, wordpress

I have task for school. I need to make Wordpress login-form plugin

**I stuck in this part:**

"On login you should send data to 3rd party login service, that will happen on server side.

*Login should be done on server side by using WP API functionality.

*This is external API service that needs to be called with CURL, here is example URL:

`Request URL: http://example.com/wp-json/example/login/?
Request Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Post body object:
{
    "username": "usernameinput",
    "password": "passwordinput"
}"`

I write some code:

**test_plugin.php**

```
<form action="wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="test_login">

add_action( 'admin_post_test_login', 'identify_user' );

function identify_user() {

        $response = wp_remote_post( 'http://wordpress.test/wp-admin/', array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization' => 'XaxHyiIwhR06isYQGKHiei6J2ZuRsFzsgCJ4NucC',),
                'body' => json_encode($user)
            )
        );

        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
            echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
        } else {
            print_r( $response );
        }
}
```

Like I understand from the task text rather, submit username/password to WP backend, then I need to make an authentication request to 3rd party site from WP backend (with CURL or similar)...

Can someone give me instructions how to make that, or some tutorial or example.